# How to create and add items to dictionary

Tags: dictionary, hashmap, racket

I am trying to create a dictionary or hash-table where keys are string and values are integers with following code:

```
(define dict #())
(dict-set! dict "bash" 1)
(displayln dict)
(dict-set! dict "racket" 1)
(displayln dict)
```

However, it gives following error:

```
dict-set!: contract violation
  expected: (dict-implements/c dict-set!)
  given: '#()
  in: the d argument of
      (->i
       ((d (dict-implements/c dict-set!))
        (k (d) (dict-key-contract d))
        (value (d) (dict-value-contract d)))
       (_r void?))
  contract from: <collects>/racket/dict.rkt
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the literal `#()` is an empty vector.

To make a mutable hash table, use `(make-hash)`.

```
 (define dict (make-hash))
```